# insert code which require where clause

Tags: asp.net

i need to insert some data in a raw. suppose first i insert username, firstname lastname  etc and then i create a session "username" from the username field

now i need to insert gender, education, photourl where username= session"username"

i am using maltiview and view

```
Protected Sub btnSubmitD1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'Dim temp As Integer = (DateTime.Now.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime("txtDOB.Text")).Days) / 365

        Dim objcmd As New SqlCommand((((("insert into Registration(UserName,FName,LName,Gender,Religion,Language,Status) values('" & Session("UserName").ToString() & "','") + txtFName.Text & "','") + txtLName.Text & "','" & ddlGender.SelectedValue.ToString() & "','") + txtReligion.Text & "','") + txtMotherTongue.Text & "','" & ddlMaritalStatus.SelectedValue.ToString() & "')", con)
```

Comment: Please use parameters in your sql statement instead of directly putting untrusted content from your textboxes into the sql statement.

Comment: Samich - How did you miss the word 'maltiview' when editing :)  That word sounds like the woman out of the film Fith Element when she says "multipass"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have created a simple form broken down in to Views.

On the first View, you want to capture the username, and name of the person, then the second view some further details and so on.  But you want to create a database entry for the user after the first view has beeen completed...

There are two fundemental ways of doing this

> a. You save all the fields in to Session variables first.  This way
>   you enter all the data at once in to the database.  It also allows any
>   field to be easily changed without extra database checks.
>
> b. More difficult is you enter the fields from the first view into the database, save
>   the returned @@IDENTITY (or whatever you use for a unique id) then use
>   that to save the fields in the following views.

For (a), whenever you swap Views, simple save/update the `Session["fieldname"] = fieldvalue`.  Then when the form is complete, you can use a statement like

```
INSERT INTO table (name,firstname,lastname,...) VALUES (@name,@firstname,@lastname,...)
```

For (b), you will first have to insert the initial View, and get the new id

```
INSERT INTO table (name,firstname,lastname) VALUES (@name,@firstname,@lastname);
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

Then for each of the following views, use the value returned from @@IDENTITY to update the table

```
UPDATE table SET gender=@gender, dob=@dob,... WHERE id=@id
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm understanding you correctly. You want to update those field values, where the username is what is stored in the session variable. You can use the following code:

```
        Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=YouDatabase;Integrated Security=True")
            Using cmdUpdate As New SqlCommand("Update Registration Set Gender=@Gender, Education=@Education, PhotoUrl=@PhotoUrl Where Username=@UserName")
               conn.Open()
               cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", "male")
               cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Education", "Degree")
               cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhotoUrl", "http://photo.com/photo.png")
               cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Session("UserName").ToString())
               cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: thnx for the reply but whether updatecommand will work when the gender, education and photourl fields are empty